# Does not listen scroll event on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe

My program works like this, I put the scroll listener on the body, which I take out of the iFrame, with a certain scroll up, I hide my fixed filter, which is in the header of the site, on all devices android it works, but there is no ios, no matter how much I scroll the filter It does not hide, it feels like a scrolling event is not being heard on an iPhone. I can not solve this problem within two days!

```
componentDidMount() {
    let body = iframe.getDocument().body;
    body.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollToFilter)
    this.setState({body})
}

scrollToFilter = (e) => {
    if(this.state.viewFilter && e.target.scrollTop > 180){
        this.setState({viewFilter:false})
    }

    if(!this.state.viewFilter && e.target.scrollTop < 160){
        this.setState({viewFilter:true})
    }
}



body {
color: @font-general-color;
background-color: @body-background-color;
font-size: @font-general-size;
.media-xs({font-size: @font-general-responsive-size;});
font-family: @font-general-name;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

html,body {
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
overflow: auto;
position:relative;
}
```

on the iPhone it does not work, as if the scrolling event is not caught

filter that hides when scrolling has position:fixed

Comment: Could you explain more, with your current information its hard to figure out whats going on also post some code

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar I expanded my question